# new network login causes Visual Studio to need new permissions?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, permissions, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Our department is in the process of moving to a new domain.  We were all given new network logins etc.  Our computers are part of the new domain, everything seems to be ok.  I've copied all my files over, but when I run visual studio, I get the classic error...

Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

Now, I know this is a permissions issue, and I assume it's happening because I'm running visual studio as a different user, and the file permissions need to be redone.  I've tried adding and granting full access to c:/users/myNewNetworkID/appData/temp for IIS_Iusers, Network services... I remember when I started this job and the PC was new that I had to change a bunch... does anyone know *exactly* what folders need to have new permissions assigned?  I also tried granting those users full access to the temp asp.net folder in Microsoft.net/framework64/... but I'm still getting this infuriatingly vague error.  any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before and have found that granting full control to the group called "Everyone" for the folder C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework[.NET FRAMEWORK VERSION]\Temporary ASP.NET Files does the job although your error could be caused by something else. The folder above is where temporary files are stored when apps are compiled for the first time *(this will probably include a shadow copy of the Ajax Control Toolkit listed in the error above)* are temporarily stored

Find this folder in Windows Explorer, right click on it, select properties, go to the security tab, grant access to the 'Everyone' group)

Comment: Isn't adding everyone full control a bit of a bad practice? I can try it, but I think the problem lies somewhere else... since I posted this, I opened 2 more projects, and they are all giving me the same message, however this is through the old account, where nothing has changed, and up until yesterday, they were working just fine.  Could something have messed with the permissions already set up?

Comment: Also, I tried adding the everyone group with full permissions to framework64/blah blah temporary asp.net files and this didn't change anything.  still got the blue squiggle of death at the top of my code :/